# emacs 23 - frame parameter alpha ignored on startup

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use the following code snippets in my init.d in order to make my emacs frames opaque:

```
(add-to-list 'initial-frame-alist '(alpha 95 95))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(alpha 95 95))
(set-frame-parameter nil 'alpha '(95 95))
```

The first should do the job already for the initial frame. The second sets the parameter for all other new frames. The third should do it on the fly (is this needed, anyways?).

Problem: The initial frame is *not* opaque. However, when I create a new frame, that one turns out to be opaque. I don't understand why the inital frame is not. Any help appreciated.

I use emacs23 on ubuntu 13.10

Comment: I too experience problems with the `initial-frame-alist`, but haven't gotten around to submitting a bug report.  A workaround for an issue I experience is to have a modification of the frame parameters in my init.el file, which fixes the initial frame after it is created:  e.g., `(modify-all-frames-parameters (list (cons 'vertical-scroll-bars nil)))`